# Hiding Menu Links Based on URL

Tags: 7, routes

Is there a way to hide menu links on the main menu based on the URL?

For instance, if my URL is 'example.com/undergraduate', the main menu links would be different than if I were to go to 'example.com/graduate'.

This obviously can't be too hard? A module would be awesome.

Comment: You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/path_access and prevent link path to be accessed (I think it checks access to the path before rendering menu link)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have page specific menu system, you can create different menu blocks and put them appropriately.

Considering your example

Main menu is nothing but a menu block, so instead of using main menu block you can have two different menu blocks let say Menu block A and Menu block B

So in block configuration for Menu block A you will put the block visibility to show on "undergraduate" only and similarly put for Menu block b put it as "graduate"

Remember to put the menu blocks in same region as your main menu. You are just toggling menu block visibility on basis of URL.